# setting core data object a second time causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, exc-bad-access

I have a customer object with two relationships, a document and an asset.

When I create an Asset I have a condition where I check for the existence of a document object in the customer.  If it does not exist, I create one and set the document's customer relationship.

Right after that, I create the asset.  However, I am getting a crash when trying to set the customer to the asset with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Whats strange is this code use to work, but I have no idea what would of changed to suddenly cause a crash here.

this is the code:

```
if (![customer inspectionDocument])  //check if a document exists
{
    // if it doesn't create one
    Document *document = [Document newDocument];
    document.customer = customer;
    //sets additional properties
}

// now create the asset
Asset *asset = [Asset newObject];
asset.customer = customer;   // <---- crash occurs here
//sets additional properties
```

Comment: Are you sure you are creating the `Document` and `Asset` objects created from the same `NSManagedObjectContext` the `Customer` object was created? That might be your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're using a relationship to store the customer reference to your document and asset. Normally, you should have a reverse relationship. Have you tried setting the document property on the customer object instead of the opposite?

```
if (![customer inspectionDocument]) {

    // if it doesn't create one
    customer.document = [Document newDocument];
}

customer.asset = [Asset newObject];
```

Comment: the relationships for customer to document and customer to asset are one to many.  is there an easy way to add to the NSSet of the customer's document and asset?

Comment: Well, i created a mutable set, added the new object to that set, then set the property back to the customer object, and i dont seem to be getting a crash anymore.  So this seemed to be the fix